# What's the probability of an intersection of two independent and one dependent events?

Tags: probability, self-study

If A and B are independent events but both are dependent on event C, how can I rewrite:

$P(A \cap B \cap C)$ ?

I was given in a question that:
$P(A \cap B \mid C)$ = $P(A \mid C)$ $P(B \mid C)$
and I'm trying to prove it to myself.

I'm stuck at proving that:
$P(A \cap B \cap C)$ = $P(A \cap C)$ $P(B \cap C)$
again, given that A and B are independent events but both are dependent on event C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a homework assignment. Please add the [tag:self-study] tag to your post.

Comment: What definitions and formulas do you have available for conditional probabilities?  Apply one and see where it leads.

Comment: Usually $P(A \cap B \cap C)\not =P(A \cap C)\,P(B \cap C)$ so you will not be able to prove equality.    Meanwhile  $P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid C) \,P(B \mid C)$ is essentially the definition of conditional independence given $C$; you might want to multiply both sides by $\big(P(C)\big)^2$ and then simplify

Comment: I guess that's why it was given... so there is no way the simplify the probability of the intersection of those three events?

Comment: Elaborating on what @Henry says, you really want A and B to be conditionally indepdent given C. So A and B being independent does not suffice.